# Akka actor granularity

Tags: java, akka, actor, thread-synchronization

I am trying to wrap my head around Akka/actors for the first time, and am a bit confused over the granularity of each Actor's responsibilities.

In my app there are `Widget`s that can be registered/unregistered with a `WidgetRegistrar`. To register itself with the `Registrar` and `Widget` is passed to the `registerWidget` method:

```
interface WidgetRegistrar {
    public void register(Widget w);
}
```

When a `Widget` attempts to register, a verification process occurs. If this process passes, then the `Widget` presents a URL that must be constantly (once a second) polled and checked (with an HTTP GET) to make sure that URL is still healthy.

My question here is: how should this work load be spread amongst actors?

I can think of several different strategies right off the bat:

- `WidgetRegistrar` actor that first somehow delegates to the `WidgetVerifier` actor (see below), and if verified, updates the `WidgetChecker` actor with the newly-registered/verified `Widget`
- `WidgetVerifier` actor that verifies a `Widget` attempting to register itself
- 1 master `WidgetChecker` that checks a URL for each registered/verified `Widget`

Or a different strategy:

- `WidgetRegistrar` actor that first somehow delegates to the `WidgetVerifier` actor (see below), and if verified, somehow instantiates a new `WidgetChecker` actor (see below)
- `WidgetVerifier` actor that verifies a `Widget` attempting to register itself
- 1 `WidgetChecker` for each registered/verified `Widget`

Or a different strategy:

- `WidgetRegistrar` actor that verifies `Widget`s right there on the spot (instead of delegating out to a separate actor), and if verified, updates the `WidgetChecker` actor with the newly-registered/verified `Widget`
- 1 master `WidgetChecker` that checks a URL for each registered/verified `Widget`

...the list of variations goes on and on.

So I ask: what is the granularity of an Akka actor, and how do I know when I should break functionality out into another actor and somehow connect the two actors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka ideology is 'let it crash', so it's best to isolate potentially dangerous functionality into a separate actor.

How i would do that - sample actor hierarchy:

```
/master
    /validator
        /authentication
        /capability
    /registrar
        /widget1
        /widget2
        /widget3
```

Assuming that you may want to have more functionality in your registrar other than register/unregister for a single widget, it's would be good to separate widgets under specific root - so, for instance, if your widget has functionality like 'update', you invoke this logic in `/registrar/widget1`, and if update has failed, `widget1` actor will die. Depending on your needs you may want to require either to reregister the widget, or set the supervisor hierarchy to restart the widget actor automatically.

With validators/verifiers and other logic - you can build either pipeline (sequential processing) or scatter-gather (parallel) on your validators, for instance:

- /master sends to /validator a message `AttemptRegister(WidgetInfo)`
- /validator sends this message to all of its children (e.g. through `ask` pattern), and is expecting `Accept(WidgetInfo)` or `Reject(WidgetInfo)` - if there are no rejections - it will send `RegisterWidget` to `/registrar` and registrar will spawn a new `/registrar/widget2`.

Of course, it all depends on the concrete use case - for instance:

- Can validation crash or block? Then you would need to have `/validator/capability/doOrDieActor1`
- Do you need sequential processing/pipeline? you may want to implement this sequence like `../authentication` will send `Pass` or `Fail` to `../authorization` that will send it to `capability` etc - and only the final actor will send `ValidationSucceeded` to `/validator`, which will in turn send `RegisterWidget` event to `registrar`